# Echo maven project version, but suppress logging

Tags: bash, logging, version, maven-3, devops

In a bash script I need to derive the pom version and store the result in an environment variable.

I can echo the version using:

```
 mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

...but unfortunately this also spews out a lot of logging noise:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...

..etc etc

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate (default-cli) @ ... --
    [INFO] 
    0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 

... etc etc

    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.764 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-23T13:26:53+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/449M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I use the quiet switch -q I get nothing...

```
$ mvn -q help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
$
```

A temporary work around might be something like:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v INFO
```

...but I would like something a bit more rigorous. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You don't want a solution with `grep`? then it isn't right to tag it with `bash` tag or any other shell tools? What exactly do you have in mind for a rigorous approach

Comment: I want a solution that is not dependent on the log level, which may change. I have no problems with grep as such. I would prefer a solution that would seperate the command output from the logging, such as directing the logging to stderr and the command output to stdin, rather than muddling them together in the same output stream.

Comment: Would it be wise to print depending on the string output alone `0.0.3-SNAPSHOT`? What are all the variable characters here? If you can let know that, we can define a regex to lookup for only such string? sounds fair?

Comment: Granted an egrep with a regex or something will work but like I said I want a way of cleanly separating the signal from the noise, in this case, the command output from the logging, rather than dealing with the consequences of the two being muddled together in the same output stream.

Comment: Then I guess you need to know which streams the logging output and command output are written into (both to stdout stream/both to stderr / one to stdout and other stderr and vice versa)

Comment: yea, and the architecture may not actually permit what I want.